# When i minimise screen the apex charts was not aligned good in angular

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I am facing issue with this apex charts when it was in full screen everything was fine and when i minimise the screen the chart was going inside thee card which was not looking good..

app.component.ts:

```
   export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
   riskByCategoryAnalysis: ChartType;
   constructor(){}
   ngOnInit(){
     this.processRiskByCategory(); 
   }

   private processRiskByCategory() {
   this.riskByCategoryAnalysis = {
    series: [this.one, this.two,
      this.three, this.four],
    chart: {
      height: 276,
      type: 'donut',
      width: '100%',

    },
    labels: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
    plotOptions: {

      pie: {
        donut: {
          size: '75%'
        }
      }
    },

    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    colors: ['#0090E7', '#99D3F5', '#1BC59C', '#A4E8D7'],
  };
 }  
 }
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="row" id="apex-chart">
                    <div class="col-md-7 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pr-0">
                        <apx-chart dir="ltr" class="apex-charts" *ngIf="riskByCategoryAnalysis"
                                   [series]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.series"
                                   [chart]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.chart"
                                   [legend]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.legend"
                                   [colors]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.colors"
                                   [labels]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.labels"
                                   [dataLabels]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.dataLabels"
                                   [plotOptions]="riskByCategoryAnalysis.plotOptions">
                        </apx-chart>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the HTML & CSS of the component? It looks like a CSS issue.

Comment: I have added html and  i dont have any css classes for this chart.

Comment: I've posted a general answer, for a more specific answer i would need a stackblitz, codepen or something of the sorts to take a deep look into it.

Comment: Could you add the ChartType definition. Since this is a type issue form TS. –

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be fixed adding configration of the [responsive](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/responsive/) property of the chart.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-donut-simple-8fnji?from-embed=&file=/src/app/app.component.ts) you can see an example on how to use the property.

In your case, something like this, should work.

```
   responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            legend: {
              position: "bottom"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: But responsive property is not working for donut chart

Comment: @vidya I have edited the answer with a link to a working example on a donut chart that changes the width & the position of the legend when the screen gets smaller.

Comment: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'responsive' does not exist in type 'ChartType'. This error was displaying.

Comment: @vidya could you share the full *app.component.ts*? The error you mention looks like an issue on the type definition of *ChartType*.

Comment: i have added the changes.please have a look.