# I am using for loop to display the tabs from api response in Angular

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
  <mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
            <mat-tab [label]="tab" *ngFor="let tab of tabNames">

           content..........


            </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
```

In the data i have 4 object that objects should be displayed as tabs.  and i should not display one tab of 1_exists in mat-tab row.please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: What is `1_exists`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the first element, or get any subset of your array, using the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe):

```
<mat-tab [label]="tab" *ngFor="let tab of tabNames | slice:1">
```

Also, for future questions, please remember this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Posting a new question should be your last resort.

And this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you with better answers.

Comment: Thank you for your time. And can you please try to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929525/when-i-minimise-screen-the-apex-charts-was-not-aligned-good-in-angular.